# The Application Data folder for Visual Studio could not be created in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

The Application Data folder for Visual Studio could not be created, this is the problem showing in my Jenkins. Before it works, all of sudden it is not working now after restarting the machine. I tried all the ways given in on-line and given in the below document too.

http://saurabharorablog.blogspot.ca/2012/06/solution-application-data-folder-for.html

Could anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this issue by simply running Visual Studio as an Administrator. This created the necessary folders and we were able to use it normally n all scenarios after that, including in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Key is: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]

Entry inside this is ‘AppData’ which had the value %APPDATA%.

Then I changed it to this value  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming

Then all the applications started working as usual. I wish any of you who find similar error message could use this solution to fix it.

[NOTE: The following link is broken from the US.  Perhaps other locations as well.  It should not be clicked as the site it reaches does not appear safe.]
Ref:http://tutewall[do not use]com/application-data-folder-for-visual-studio-could-not-be-created/